# Is a set of vectors mapped to by linearly independent vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example take $T\in L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)$ with $v_1,...,v_m$ linearly independent. Does this imply that $Tv_i=w_i$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can map all of them to the zero vector, for example.

Answer (score 2):

No, it need not be.  As an extreme example, consider the zero map $0: v\mapsto 0$ for every $v$.  Then certainly $\{w_1,\ldots, w_n\}=\{0\}$ is not linearly independent.

In general, if $a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n=0$, then $T(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n)=0$.  Thus, the only thing we can conclude is that $a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n$ is in the kernel, and the kernel need not be trivial ($\{0\}$).